# Al momento de imprimir me salen caracteres y símbolos al azar

Tags: c++

Necesito calcular el ganador de 3 partidos de futbol 3 equipos(A,B Y C) que juagron todos contra todos. El resultado debe de ser la letra del equipo ganador, de ser empate debe de salir E, no hay necesidad de imprimir que equipos empataron.
partido 1: A vs B
partido 2: A vs C
partido 3: B vs C.
ayuda porfa... :3

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//calculo de los resultados del equipo A
int calcularResultadoEquipoA(int partido_1_A, int partido_2_A) {
    int resultado_equipo_A = partido_1_A + partido_2_A;
    return resultado_equipo_A * 1;
}

//calculo de los resultados del equipo b
int calcularResultadoEquipoB(int partido_1_B, int partido_3_B) {
    int resultado_equipo_B = partido_1_B + partido_3_B;
    return resultado_equipo_B * 1;
}

//calculo de los resultados del equipo C
int calcularResultadoEquipoC(int partido_2_C, int partido_3_C) {
    int resultado_equipo_C = partido_2_C + partido_3_C;
    return resultado_equipo_C * 1;
}

//comparacion de puntaje de datos dentro de booleanos para saber que equipo tiene mas puntaje o empatados
char compararResultados(int partido_1_A, int partido_1_B, int partido_2_A, int partido_2_C, int partido_3_B, int partido_3_C) {
    bool comparar_A_y_B = (calcularResultadoEquipoA > calcularResultadoEquipoB);
    bool empate_A_Y_B = (calcularResultadoEquipoA == calcularResultadoEquipoB);

    bool comparar_A_y_C = (calcularResultadoEquipoA > calcularResultadoEquipoC);
    bool empate_A_y_C = (calcularResultadoEquipoA == calcularResultadoEquipoC);

    bool comparar_B_y_A = (calcularResultadoEquipoB > calcularResultadoEquipoA);
    bool empate_B_y_A = (calcularResultadoEquipoB == calcularResultadoEquipoA);

    bool comparar_B_y_C = (calcularResultadoEquipoB > calcularResultadoEquipoC);
    bool empate_B_y_C = (calcularResultadoEquipoB == calcularResultadoEquipoC);

    bool comparar_C_y_A = (calcularResultadoEquipoC > calcularResultadoEquipoA);
    bool empate_C_y_A = (calcularResultadoEquipoC == calcularResultadoEquipoA);

    bool comparar_C_y_B = (calcularResultadoEquipoC > calcularResultadoEquipoB);
    bool empate_C_y_B = (calcularResultadoEquipoC == calcularResultadoEquipoB);

    //retorno de un char teniendo el resultado de la operacion de la comparacion
    return (comparar_A_y_B * 'A') +
        (empate_A_Y_B * 'E') +

        (comparar_A_y_C * 'A') +
        (empate_A_y_C * 'E') +

        (comparar_B_y_A * 'B') +
        (empate_B_y_A * 'E') +

        (comparar_B_y_C * 'B') +
        (empate_B_y_C * 'E') +

        (comparar_C_y_A * 'C') +
        (empate_C_y_A * 'E') +

        (comparar_C_y_B * 'C') +
        (empate_C_y_B * 'E');
}

int main() {
    //Entrada de datos
    int partido_1_A, partido_1_B, partido_2_A, partido_2_C, partido_3_B, partido_3_C;
    cout << "1er Partido - Equipo A vs Equipo B: " << endl;
    cout << "Goles Equipo A: ";
    cin >> partido_1_A;
    cout << "Goles Equipo B: ";
    cin >> partido_1_B;

    cout << "2do Partido - Equipo A vs Equipo C " << endl;
    cout << "Goles Equipo A: ";
    cin >> partido_2_A;
    cout << "Goles Equipo C: ";
    cin >> partido_2_C;

    cout << "3er Partido - Equipo B vs Equipo C " << endl;
    cout << "Goles Equipo B: ";
    cin >> partido_3_B;
    cout << "Goles Equipo C: ";
    cin >> partido_3_C;
    //Salida de datos
    cout << "Ganador: " << compararResultados(partido_1_A, partido_1_B, partido_2_A, partido_2_C, partido_3_B, partido_3_C);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que probablemente los caracteres raros de los que hablas aparecen en el resultado final.

Se deben a qué estás haciendo operaciones aritméticas con los caracteres:

```
(comparar_A_y_B * 'A') + (empate_A_Y_B * 'E') + ...
```

Para entender mejor lo que sucede, analicemos el primer paréntesis.

Para operar entre tipos diferentes, debe suceder una conversión. En este caso, hay una conversión implícita a `char`.

¿Qué valor tomará? La realidad es que cada compilador tiene la libertad de implementarlo de forma diferente. Supongamos que **0** corresponde a **false** y **1** a **verdadero**.

Posiblemente te estés preguntando: ¿Por qué me hablas de números si un `char` contiene un símbolo?

Resulta que las computadoras solo entienden ceros y unos. Pero esos dos valores son suficientes para agrupar unos cuantos y que a cada combinación posible le corresponda un número o un símbolo o al revés. A los procesos de convertir de algo a binario o de binario a algo se les conoce como codificación y decodificación respectivamente.

Si intentas leer el valor numérico de una letra, por ejemplo `A` verás que se corresponde con 65. Cada correspondencia está plasmada en el código ASCII.

---

Ya explicadas estas cosas, supongamos que `comparar_A_y_B` es `true`.

Esto:

```
comparar_A_y_B * 'A'
```

Es lo mismo que:

```
1 * 65 = 65
```

El resultado es 65, por lo tanto el carácter que obtienes es de nuevo, 'A'.

Evaluemos el siguiente paréntesis suponiendo que (aunque no lo hayas hecho así) `empate_A_Y_B` es `true`:

```
empate_A_Y_B * 'E'
1 * 69 = 69
```

Volviste a obtener 'E'.

Como en C++ sumar caracteres no los concatena, si sumas los primeros 2 paréntesis ya obtienes `65 + 69 = 134` que corresponde al símbolo `å`.

Si sigues sumando obtendrás un "carácter raro".

---

La solución es replantear el algoritmo.

No está muy claro qué es lo que quieres hacer o cómo. También tiene problemas de diseño que te dificultarán si quieres que sea independiente de la cantidad de equipos y partidos pero te daré algunas sugerencias.

La función `compararResultados` como está programada, intenta determinar el ganador en función a los goles totales de cada equipo. Lo menciono porque si la idea es que el ganador de que sea el que más partidos ganó, no necesariamente es el que más goles hizo a lo largo de todos los partidos.

Intentando seguir la intención del código, sería más fácil que el contenido de la función sea algo como:

```
int totalGolesA = partido1GolesA + partido2GolesA + ...;
int totalGolesB = partido1GolesB + ...;
int totalGolesC = ...;

// Empate
if (totalGolesA == totalGolesB && totalGolesA == totalGolesC)
    return 'N'; // Ninguno

if (totalGolesA > totalGolesB && totalGolesA > totalGolesC)
    return 'A';

if (totalGolesB > totalGolesA && totalGolesB > totalGolesC)
    return 'B';

// Si no gano ninguno de los otros 2, significa que debió haber ganado C.
return 'C';
```

---

Contemplando la posibilidad de que quieras concatenar los caracteres, puedes usar [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) que sobrecarga el operador `+=`.

```
std::string str = "Hola";
str += '!';
str += std::string(" Son las ");
str += 5;
str += " de la tarde.";
std::cout << str;
// Hola! Son las 5 de la tarde.
```

---

Algunas observaciones:

- Los paréntesis en las líneas como la siguiente son innecesarios:

  bool comparar_C_y_B = (calcularResultadoEquipoC > calcularResultadoEquipoB);

Porque el operador de asignación `=` tiene la menor precedencia, se evaluará primero lo que está a su derecha se asignará el resultado.

- No veo las variables `calcularResultadoEquipoA`, `calcularResultadoEquipoB` y `calcularResultadoEquipoC`. Si te refieres a las funciones, faltan los paréntesis.
- En lugar de hacer una función por equipo, ya que estás haciendo lo mismo en cada una, puedes hacer una sola y variar los datos que pasas como parámetro según el equipo.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entendi del programa. Estas intentando comparar valores de tipos *int* en la funcion *CompararResultados*, mientras que tambien, le asignas a la misma funcion, el tipo *char*.
En la salida de datos:

```
cout << "Ganador: " << compararResultados(partido_1_A, partido_1_B, partido_2_A, partido_2_C, partido_3_B, partido_3_C);
    return 0;
}
```

Quieres comparar un resultado que va a dar de tipo *Booleano*, mientras que tu esperas que el programa devuelve un dato de tipo *Char*.
Intenta realizar nuevamente la funcion "compararResultados".